# algorithm to combinatorics

Tags: java, combinatorics

I am trying to solve a combinatorics problem, it seems easy, but i am having some trouble with it.

If i have at most X tables, and N persons to sit on the tables, Each table can have 1 to N seating places, and I can only sit persons in one side of a rectangular table( so the order how people sit matters).

I want to make a code that can calculate all the distributions of seating places from 1 up to K tables.

For example, if I have 12 persons and 1 table i have 479001600 ways of seating persons( thats easy to calculate I've used Factorial of 12).

But if I have 12 persons and 3 tables i have 4390848000 ways of seating persons. I've tried different solutions but i was not able to find the correct one.

I've tried to divided the 12 in 3, then o use factorial of the result (it didnt work), i've tried to use 12! * 3( it didn't work too).

Can some one give me a tip in a algorithm that i can use?

Comment: How do you know that the answer "4390848000" is correct if you don't know how to calculate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read an article about [Lah Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lah_number), it should help.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think 4,390,848,000 is a correct answer (if counting empty seats).

The number of ways to arrange N people into X tables of N seats is equivalent to arranging N people to 1 table of (N*X) seats. The result is pretty obvious: (NX choose N × N!).

- NX choose N = number of ways to put N people into NX seats without considering permutations.
- N! = number of permutations of these N people.

e.g.

```
[a b|_ _]  [a _|b _]  [a _|_ b] 
[_ a|b _]  [_ a|_ b]  [b a|_ _]
[_ _|a b]  [b _|a _]  [_ b|a _]  = 4 choose 2 * 2! = 12.
[b _|_ a]  [_ b|_ a]  [_ _|b a]
```

But (36 choose 12 × 12!) = 599,555,620,984,320,000.

Even if the tables are identical (remove a factor of 3! = 6), the result 99,925,936,830,720,000 is still much larger than 4,390,848,000.